# How to safely go through components of QEntity in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Here if I run the code with `components()` line commented out I get a window with a purple torus as expected but if I just call the `components()` on the `torus_entity` (uncomment the line) the torus disappears.

I can print the components from the `components()` but trying to usem them returns an error saying it was deleted, for example: deleted torus_mesh.
The `material` variable which can be reused for various models also throws error saying the material was deleted if you try to use it on any line beyond the `components()` call.

Qt documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qentity.html#components

Documentation says components returns a list of `QComponent` nothing about the deletion, I don't know how to use this properly?

I'd like to go through the components and check them and change their properties, for example change position and/or scale through `QTransform` component.

I could go down the QT version to 5.12.12 but I don't know how to do this for PyQt5 so it builds against this QT version.

I've tried it in PyQt6, also in Qt5 (c++, but different version then the PyQt5 uses) and it works just fine in both, this might be a bug in PyQt5/Qt5? I wonder if there's a workaround for this (maybe making adjustments in some PyQt5 files?)?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt3DCore import QEntity, QTransform, QAspectEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QVariant, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QVector3D, QQuaternion, QGuiApplication, QColor
from PyQt5.Qt3DRender import QCamera, QCameraLens, QRenderAspect, QDirectionalLight, QSceneLoader
from PyQt5.Qt3DInput import QInputAspect
from PyQt5.Qt3DExtras import QForwardRenderer, QMetalRoughMaterial, QCylinderMesh, QSphereMesh, QTorusMesh, \
    Qt3DWindow, QOrbitCameraController, QPlaneMesh
 
 
def create_scene():
    root_entity = QEntity()
 
    d_light_entity = QEntity(root_entity)
    direction_light = QDirectionalLight()
    direction_light.setColor(QColor(255, 254, 245))
    direction_light.setIntensity(2)
    d_light_entity.addComponent(direction_light)
 
    material = QMetalRoughMaterial(root_entity)
    material.setBaseColor(QColor(160, 30, 160))
    material.setRoughness(.5)
 
    # Torus
    torus_entity = QEntity(root_entity)
    torus_mesh = QTorusMesh()
    torus_mesh.setRadius(5)
    torus_mesh.setMinorRadius(1)
    torus_mesh.setRings(100)
    torus_mesh.setSlices(20)
    torus_transform = QTransform()
    torus_transform.setScale3D(QVector3D(1.5, 1, 0.5))
    torus_entity.addComponent(torus_mesh)
    torus_entity.addComponent(torus_transform)
    torus_entity.addComponent(material)
 
    #components = torus_entity.components()
 
    return root_entity
 
 
def main(argv):
    app = QGuiApplication(argv)
 
    view = Qt3DWindow()
    view.defaultFrameGraph().setClearColor(QColor(39, 39, 39))
    scene = create_scene()
 
    camera = view.camera()
    camera.lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 15.0/9.0, .1, 1000.0)
    camera.setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40.0))
    camera.setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0))
 
    view.setRootEntity(scene)
    view.show()
 
    return sys.exit(app.exec())
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I can reproduce the problem using pyqt-5.15.7. It looks like a pyqt bug, so please report it on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). The maintainer usually fixes bugs like this fairly quickly, which means a snapshot should become available that you can build against the latest Qt5. The only work-around I can see at the moment would be to subclass QEntity and reimplement the `*component` methods to use an internal list.

Comment: Thanks, I also came to the conclusion of it being a bug, I'm just not sure if it's pyqt but or qt specific ;0.

Comment: It's definitely a pyqt5 bug.